# Unity cant find function definition with Quick Graph Library

Tags: unity-game-engine, quickgraph

Im using the quick graph library with my unity project. Im using visual studio as my editor and it gives no errors to this line but when i try to compile with unity it says it cant find the function ShortestPathsDijkstra defined for graph. This line is definitely correct since I got it of the quick graph documentation.

```
TryFunc<string, IEnumerable<Edge<string>>> tryGetPaths =      graph.ShortestPathsDijkstra(edgeCost, root);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [QuickGraph](https://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) is a portable library, i.e. supports .Net **4.0** ...

In the current version of Unity, this is **NOT** supported. You can use library that upports .Net **3.5**, this is the highest .net version that is supported.

> Unity currently supports .NET 2.0/3.5 era functionality for both the C# compiler and the class libraries.

See this link: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/.